# Phrases similar to "pleased to meet you"

Tags: internet, greetings

What phrases can I use instead of *pleased to meet you*? I'm especially interested in using it as a greeting when chatting to a person for the first time online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, the closest in meaning would be *pleased/delighted to make your acquaintance* ([theFreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/delighted+to+make+your+acquaintance)).

Also I believe good old *how do you do* will work just fine here.

Comment: +1: Emily Post prefers "How do you do" when meeting someone for the first time.  She writes that terms like "pleased", "pleasure", "delighted", etc. are over the top when you know nothing about that person.

Comment: I think many parents might be concerned if they found their teenage daughter chatting online to someone who typed *"delighted to make your acquaintance"*. I myself would be likely to assume we were dealing with some kind of weirdo.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Philoto's contributions:

- Nice to meet you.
- Good to know you.
- Pleasure.
- Charmed. (Rather old-fashioned, and usually said to someone of the opposite [or preferred] sex.)

On a related note, bear in mind that "Nice meeting you," despite its similarity to "Nice to meet you," is more commonly said at the *end* of a first meeting, rather than the beginning.

Comment: I'm in doubt regarding the  word "meet[ing]" in virtual meetings, but I saw an appropriate question on this site regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am fond of "Well met", although it is seldom used in a modern context.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised nobody mentioned *glad to meet you*.

Answer (score 0):

"Nice to meet you" is great for meeting someone for a first time. "Nice to see you" might be more appropriate if it was already someone you knew.  If you were meeting someone you know already with someone new both at the same time, I believe it would be more appropriate to make a priority towards the person that I did not know and say, "Nice to meet you".

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few:

- *Pleased to meet you*
- *Glad to see you*
- *Good to see you*
- *Nice to see you*